# Google actions builder fulfillment webhook is not passing user access token to the backend

Tags: access-token, actions-builder

We were using Dialogflow before for creating intents and the webhook used to get access token in "Authorization" header. Now we are in the process of changing it to Actions builder as the Dialogflow integration is not working anymore to add new intents in Google Action.
Now we are testing the actions in simulator and we are having authorization problem as the action builder webhook is not passing user access token. How to identify user now without the access token?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that we are getting access token in "Authorization" header if the account linking type is "OAUTH". I changed the account linking type from Google sign in & OAUTH to OAUTH and we started getting access token.